# keepin scroll position fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I am prepending HTML into some div, but when I scroll down and new content is prepended, the position changes and I can't read anymore.
Is there a way to fix this so can new post can be added on top of each div and still continuing reading without correcting the scroll?

Here is a snippet of instructions I am using:

html:

`<div class=".col-md-4"> </div>`

js:

`var new_div= "<div> <img src="picture.jpg" /> </div>";
$('.col-md-4').prepend(new_div);`

Comment: Are you able to post the code in a working jsfiddle or snippet so we can visually see the results of your code?

Comment: @JoeL posts are coming from an external oauth enabled API and Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    var new_div= $("<div class==\"div\"><img src=\"picture.jpg\" />" +
       Some text </div>");
 $('.page-wrapper').before(new_div);
});
```

Comment: The window glitches when I scroll. Made the render slow. And when I am on top, I don't see the new data when there are new posts. Posts are coming from external API.